# Is naming variables after their type a bad practice?

Tags: c++, variables, naming, naming-conventions

I'm programming C++ using the underscore naming style (as opposed to camel case) which is also used by the STL and boost. However, since both types and variables/functions are named all lower case, a member variable declaration as follows will lead to compiler errors (or at least trouble):

```
position position;
```

A member variable named *position* which is of type *position*. I don't know how else to name it: It's generally *a position*, but it is also *the position* of the object. In camel case, this would be fine with the compiler:

```
Position position;
```

But in C++ it causes problems. I don't want to switch to camel case, use Hungarian notation or add a trailing underscore because of that, so I'm wondering: Is it a good practice to name a member like a type anyways?

In C, it is pretty common to use cryptic one-letter variables for this:

```
int i;
```

But I find that a bit, well, cryptic:

```
position p;
```

Are there any rules of thumb for variable naming I can use to avoid this?

There are more examples in my code if you need something to work on:

```
mouse_over(entity entity) // Returns true if the mouse is over the entity

manager &manager; // A reference to the framework's manager

audio audio; // The audio subsystem
```

**Edit:**

I was curious to see if Bjarne Stroustrup himself has something to say on this issue. Apparently, he hasn't, but he suggests coding conventions that would work around my compiler problems:

> For example, capitalize nonstandard library user-defined types and start nontypes with a lowercase letter

That'd be consistent with STL and boost, so I might use that. However, most of you agree that this naming should be avoided whether it compiles or not. So does Stroustrup:

> it is unwise to choose names that differ only by capitalization.

Comment: Type names start with upper case. Variable names start with lowercase. And variable names are never short. Try searching your source for all instances of the variable `i`.

Comment: Code complete has a chapter about naming variables.

Comment: `i` is perfectly fine for the name of an index variable or iterator which is local to a 3-4 line for loop.  Definitely not recommended for member variables though.

Comment: @Martin: the trick is to search for `[^\w]i[^\w]` ;)

Comment: @Matthieu: That will not work: for (i = 5; i++; i< 7) {} Regular expressions that use space in particular space don't help ;-)

Comment: @Martin: actually `[^\w]` match any non alpha numerical character, since c++ identifiers are composite of `[a-zA-Z0-9_] == \w` this regular expression match the 3 `i` you exposed above... and by the way, I think you exchanged `i++` and `i<7`.

Comment: @Matthieu M: You must be using a different definition of regular expression that are particular to your environment that I use.

Comment: @Martin: what environment do you use? `\w` is a word character in grep, egrep, python, perl, and Windows PowerShell, and `[^\w]` is a non-word character, nothing to do with whitespace. Matthieu's regex doesn't catch `i` at the start or end of the string being searched, but that's rarely an issue in code - as long as files start with some boilerplate and end with a newline you can search multi-line, and as long as lines start with some indents and end with a semi-colon or backslash you can search line-wise. Weirdly-formatted code can break a line-wise search, though.

Comment: Of course if your environment (perhaps some ropey text editor or IDE) doesn't support `\w` (or even better `\W`), you could use `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]i[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Pain to type, though.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem (albeit in java where some of the answers below don't apply). My 2 cents is that sometimes the flaw is not in the name of the variable but of the class name. Suppose a type name is exactly what you would have called the variable if you didn't have this clash, would it not qualify as a good name in that circumstance? Avoiding a name that seems to be a good description of it seems like inverted reasoning in that particular circumstance.

Comment: "That'd be consistent with STL and boost"... Huh, it's not consistent. They use lowercase for types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The local meaning is rarely a good unique global description of the type:

```
cartesian_point_2d position;  // rectangular, not polar coordinates
mouse_over(ui_entity entity); // not a business layer entity
xyz_manager& manager;         // what's a manager without something to manage?
audio_system audio;
```

Comment: It's impressive how you could come up with sane suggestions for all of my examples like this. Did you use any rules of thumb or is it just something one learns with time? I'll sit down and think about each duplicate name carefully now.

Comment: From experience, but that doesn't mean there aren't patterns you can apply.  First, notice that in every case I changed the type name.  That's because the variable has context, moreso than the type.  Another way to add context with types is with namespaces.  Then I tried to think of another application where the same word might be used but the type could not be, and added some distiguishing characteristic to the type name.  For example, weather satellites also have position, which might be (latitude, longitude, altitude).

Comment: Please note that I'm still unhappy with `audio_system`, I picked that because that was your own comment about it, but I would prefer something like `pcm_audio_player` or `midi_audio_processor` or `wavfile_audio_recorder` that tells what type of audio and whether it records, plays, or modifies the audio stream.

Comment: Well, it's the audio subsystem of a game engine - audio_system is pretty good actually. The only thing I'm still unhappy with is "engine_manager" (that's what I called it) because it resides in the namespace "engine", it's name is: "engine:engine_manager" and that is a bit redundant.

Comment: Then `game_engine::audio_mixer` and `game_engine::asset_manager` are sounding better to me.  The original names just didn't carry enough information to make really good suggestions.  The only "manager" in a game engine I can think of that shouldn't be broken down further is a `game_engine::class_factory`, other things might be `asset_manager` (which unpacks sounds/sprite images/textures/AI scripts from disk), `sprite_manager`, `memory_manager`, `saved_game_manager`, `window_manager`, etc and these are all different enough in responsibility to not belong in the same class.

Comment: If you can't describe the responsibilities of your `game_engine::manager` in under 20 words without using the term `engine` then there are probably several smaller leaner classes begging to come out during refactoring.

Comment: Well, the engine_manager basically just orchestrates the creation of the various systems. I did that because some code has to be executed before any system can be initialised and I didn't know where else to put it. I might call it "system_manager".

Comment: Maybe `game_engine::startup`?

Comment: Hm, sounds good as well :) I think I'm slowly starting to develop some naming skills, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Giving a variable the same name as its type is almost always a bad idea, because it makes it very difficult to tell what code refers to the type and what code refers to the variable.  For example, consider the following class:

```
struct position
{
    void operator()() { }
};

// later on, somewhere:
position position;
```

Now, if we see a line of code that uses:

```
position()
```

we can't readily tell whether that constructs a `position` object or calls `position::operator()()`.  We have to go back and see whether there is an object named `position` currently in scope.

Naming conventions are a very touchy, subjective, and argumentative thing.  I would just recommend picking one that distinguishes types from variables in some way.  Personally, I choose to capitalize my types and leave my variables as starting with a lowercase letter.

It doesn't really matter *how* you distinguish them (your suggestions of using capitalization or a trailing underscore are both common), just so long as your usage is consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Naming variables after their *type* specifically is indeed a bad practice. The code is supposed to be as type-independent as possible. That implies that any references to actual types should be restricted to declarations (again, as much as possible). Trying to embed type information into variable name would violate that principle. Don't do it.

What one might want to embed into variable name is the variable's *semantical meaning*. Like "width", "length", "index", "coordinate", "rectangle", "color", "string", "converter" and so on. Unfortunately, many people, when they see it, incorrectly assume that these portions of the names are intended to describe the *type* of the variable. This misunderstanding often makes them to engage into that bad practice (of naming variables after their types) later in their code.

A classic well-known example of such misunderstanding is so called *Hungarian notation*. Hungarian notation implies prefixing variable names with special unified prefixes that describe the semantic of the variable. In this original form Hungarian notation is an extremely useful good naming convention. However, in many practical cases it gets distorted into something completely different: prefixing the variable names with something that describes their *type*. The latter is certainly not a good idea.

Comment: @John: if you hate Hungarian notation, why give +1 to an answer which praises Hungarian notation? ;-)

Comment: In object oriented languages, is it a bad idea to write `Position position`? If yes, what would be a better name to the local variable of type `Position`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a bad practice. Variable names should be more specific if they have a long lifetime or important meaning (temporaries are ok). Remember that C++ is very strictly typed- you can't have a variable and not be very sure what it's type is. A variable Type type, for example, basically just means that it doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I capitalise my class names.

I disagree with, "it is unwise to choose names that differ only by capitalization", in this specific case. It's unwise to choose names which are confusingly similar. `PoSItIoN` and `PoSiTIoN` are confusingly similar. `Position` and `position` are not. Just make sure that when you search the code, you know and can control whether you're doing so case-sensitive or insensitive.

In cases where I have a function that only uses one variable of a particular type, then I might well name it after the type, since in English if something was, "the only position we're talking about", we'd refer to it as, "the position". Hence the variable name could reasonably be `position`.

Failing that, in your examples I might go with:

```
position pos;  // pretty sure people will realise I don't mean "positron".

mouse_over(entity target) // Returns true if the mouse is over the entity

manager &fmanager; // A reference to the framework's manager

devices::audio audio; // The audio subsystem
audio self; // "this" audio subsystem
audio audio_out; // The audio subsystem I'm configured to use for output
```

The last example is supposed to indicate that these problems might be solved by namespaces - outside the namespace in which `audio` is defined, you can safely refer to it as `audio`. Inside that namespace, functions operating on the audio subsystem frequently either are parts of the `audio` class interface which just happen to be free functions (in which case use conventions like `self`, `other`, `lhs`, `rhs`), or else are some kind of layered device or system which have an audio subsystem as a dependency (in which case, dependency for what purpose?).

`entity` and `manager` are terrible names for classes, by the way, since neither of them tells you anything about what the class represents. Every discrete thing is an "entity", and while not everything manages something else, "manage" is hopelessly vague.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I picked up the old MFC practice of prefixing member variables with m_, as in "m_position." A lot of the Java people would do "thePosition" for essentially the same reason, though if you pointed out the similarity at the time they'd turn funny colors and rant at you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "problem" on a regular basis. I think it's a problem of abstration: In case of Position I'd suggest to abstract a bit more and introduce a type Point or something like that. Or specify what position is ment:

```
position mouse_pointer_pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and semi-wrong answer: If you have enough variables that you're working with in one place that you need non-cryptic variable names, maybe you have too many variables.

Though I actually disagree with that, to some extent.  I think it has a grain of truth, but only that.

Some short variable names in C++ are just traditional and people know what they mean because they've been programming in C/C++ for awhile.  Using `i` for an index variable is an example.

I think variable names should be named for their purpose.  What's the position the position of?  What's the manager managing?  Why does this particular instance of the audio subsystem need to exist?

The trailing `_` notation is used to distinguish member variable names.  It can be very helpful when someone starts mentioning `x` out of nowhere to see `x_` and know that it's coming from the class, and isn't declared in an enclosing scope or the global scope.

Comment: IMO, short, cryptic names are okay for local variables and parameters. But member variables? I'm not sure if that wouldn't be confusing.

Comment: @Noarth - And, apparently, my answer was confusing.  Oh, well.  :-)

Comment: Downvote for providing an answer you acknowledge to be semi-wrong and confusing.

Comment: I think it's a good argument that having too many variables visible in the same scope is bad sign. There's been a slow but clear trend over the decades in the evolution of languages to combat this. Even the C language has evolved to allow variable declarations anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can just follow existing guidelines, e.g. [Google's C++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#General_Naming_Rules)

It's good to be aware of naming being an important issue, but in my experience
thinking too much about it is as harmful as not being aware of it.

I've experimented with Hungarian and didn't like it, most good programmers I
know don't use it.

The main point I would make is it makes code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do this on occasions and it does not cause problems in the Microsoft world. For example,

```
class compiler
{
    symbol_table symbol_table;
};
```

has never caused any confusion. By the way, I called my cat 'cat' and that hasn't caused confusion either.

Comment: I'll add that if you ever need to refer again to the type after a variable with the same name has been declared, you can add "class" or "struct" before the type to disambiguate (just like you're forced to do in plain C if you don't have a typedef).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with this naming convention imo is that it's unclear to the programmer whether an expression refers to a type or an object. A way to eliminate such ambiguity is by wrapping your code inside a namespace (as it should) and using explicit qualifications, even on internal usage:

```cpp
namespace my_ns {

struct audio { ... };
struct string { ... };

// Internal function whose logic doesn't require explicit qualifications.
void do_something()
{
    // Use explicit qualification nevertheless.
    my_ns::audio audio;
    audio.play("impenetrable.sd2"); // okay

    my_ns::string string;
    string.size();          // okay
    // string{}.size();     // oof, tryna re-instantiate object? compilation error
    my_ns::string{}.size(); // okay, size of just created temporary string
}

}
```

This is much like the way you use standard types such as `std::string`. Since all user-defined types will be qualified with their namespace, there'll be no ambiguity between types and objects. The downside of this is, of course, more verbosity:

```cpp
namespace my_ns {

struct audio {
    // Using explicit qualification; pretty verbose.
    void play(my_ns::string a1, my_ns::string a2, my_ns::string a3);

    // Without explicit qualification; saves 21 characters.
    void play(string a1, string a2, string a3);
};

}
```