# In C, can struct members use the same name as a type?

Tags: c, syntax, struct

For example, is the following valid C code?

```
typedef struct {
    /* ... */
} foo;

typedef struct {
    foo foo; /* Is it ok that 'foo' == 'foo'? */
} bar;
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: Don't do that, simply for readability reasons. Even declaring a field `struct foo foo` is not readable, even if legal. Have some easily understandable (& guessable) naming conventions.

Comment: it works (http://liveworkspace.org/code/3vcKtX$2), it's not readable, try a style such as `foo_t` or `Foo`.

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592378/is-naming-variables-after-their-type-a-bad-practice

Comment: @TomerArazy sometimes you pick up differences in compilers, or situations where it is sometimes legal and sometimes not legal.  Trying is actually somewhat the *wrong* thing to do here; you will acquire unfound confidence that the way it worked the one time you tried it, is the way it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that is valid C (although it is not readable and should be avoided).

Types identifiers and struct members identifiers live in different name spaces.

See C99, 6.2.3p1 Name spaces of identifiers:

> [...] there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>   — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations [...]
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name
>   space for its members [...]
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers [...]

Comment: That quote doesn't mention `typedef`'d identifiers

Comment: @Matt `typedef` identifiers are *ordinary identifiers*.